# Calculate current date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing something to where the user puts in a date. Then it would compare the date input by the user and is subtracted by current date. Is there some code I can use for python ask the user for the date? And is there a way I can have python check the date on device it is on? Thanks I’m advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to ask user for a date:

```
from datetime import datetime


usr_input = str(input('Enter date(yyyy-mm-dd): '))
usr_date = datetime.strptime(usr_input, "%Y-%m-%d")
 
print(usr_date)
```

You might find this link useful in getting current date and time:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/get-current-date-time-python

Also you could check this post:
[How to get the Date and Time of Current Location in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118458/how-to-get-the-date-and-time-of-current-location-in-python)

Comment: `input()` returns a string already - no need to convert it